# How to avoid column vertical line inside multicol environment

Tags: two-column, multicol

I use

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article} 
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.0pt}
```

to write a two-column document with a a visible vertical line separation.

However, when I try to use `\begin{multicols}` to type a two-column section inside one of the columns of the page, the vertical line appears. How can we avoid this line?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: just locally set it back to 0pt before the multicols (which is presumably inside some minipage or other enviornment that limits the scope.)

Comment: How do I set it back to 0pt in a mini page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that a `multicols` environment will not work if it extends past a main column break, in two column format.

Set `\columnseprule` to zero locally:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{multicols}{2}\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
abc def ghi jklmno
abc def ghi jklmno
abc def ghi jklmno
abc def ghi jklmno
abc def ghi jklmno
abc def ghi jklmno
\end{multicols}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, using `tasks`, for instance, will avoid the usage of `multicols`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\newenvironment{problem}
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \noindent\textbf{\theproblem}.\ignorespaces}
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
\newcounter{problem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{problem}
Compute the following integrals
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[a])](2)
\task $\displaystyle\int 7\sqrt{7x-1}\,dx$
\task $\displaystyle\int \frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx$
\task $\displaystyle\int\sin(2x)\,dx$
\end{tasks}
\end{problem}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used it right now.